# how to find the hidden type value in webpage?====> <input type="hidden" id="rating" name="rating" value="">

Tags: javascript, html, hidden, test-results

I am a student who wanna know my test result before it's official grade announcement date.
i am wondering if there is any ways to find out my test result which is a hidden type value in the announcement webpage?

what I searched to find out the early test result was like;

1. click F12 button in the announcement webpage
2. search "rating"
3. know your test result

However many ppl used this early test result finding method, the test result type turned into hidden type value which was like ; input type="hidden" id="rating" name="rating" value="".

Is there any easy way to know the hidden value? Is it hard to know?

I am completely outsider of IT area and just don't know the first thing about it so can anyone please give me any advises to me about this issue?
Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function printIt(){
   alert(document.getElementById('abcId').value);
   alert(document.formName.elements['abcName'].value);
}
```

```html
<h1>Access Hidden value in JavaScript</h1>
<form name="formName">
    <input type=hidden id="abcId" name="abcName" 
                  value="It is hidden value"/>

    <input type=button value="Get Value" onclick="printIt()" />
</form>
```